# Angular ngx translate not allowed in css tooltip in button

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

On an angular 9 project I am using ngx-translate and also have so css for tooltips.

In app.component.html I've added a button.

```
<button
    type="button"
    tooltip={{ 'TITLE' | translate }}
    tooltip-position='right'>
</button>
```

I have an issue with this line:

```
tooltip={{ 'TITLE' | translate }}
```

I've also tried doing it like this:

```
tooltip="{{ 'TITLE' | translate }}"
```

But I get:

```
Can't bind to 'tooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.
```

But I know it works because when I do this:

```
tooltip="Some text here"
```

It will show the tooltip.

How can I fix this? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [title]="'TITLE' | translate"

Comment: That didn't work. I've getting: Errors parsing template: Unexpected closing tag "button". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.

Comment: i missed double quotes. changed it. try now.

Comment: Yeah but I'm getting the unstyled title and not the styled tooltip that I wanted

Comment: for styled tooltip which library you are using?

Comment: Just css, no libraries. Created a class called tooltip

Comment: there is no tooltip propertly for buttons by default. either you create a css class so use it with class attribute?

Answer (score 0):

hello faced the same problem as you, I use a translator and at the same time I want to translate the popup, here is the result of how to do it using the title attribute, and css, but add a different translation for you depending on the selected language, just add to the attribute name in square brackets

```css
*[title] {
  position: relative;
}

*[title]::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -34px;
  left: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #393838;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  color: white;
}

*[title]:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div title="Hello muffin!">
  Hello Sweetie!
</div>

<div [title]=" 'Hi Muffin!' | translate">
     Hello Sweetie!
</div>
```